# How can I resolve a dependency on something on the current request?

Tags: ninject, ioc-container

I'm setting up dependency injection in my ASP.NET Web API application. I have a scenario where a dependency has a dependency on something on the current request (the hostname, for example).

So how can I use the current request as a dependency?

Below is what I've been able to come up with, but `HttpContext.Current` won't work in a self-hosted scenario.

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>()
    .ToMethod((context) => 
    {
        string hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        var foo = FooFactory.GetByHostName(hostName);
        return foo;
    })
    .InRequestScope();
```

I'm currently using Ninject, but I can switch to a different IoC container if there's one that can handle this scenario better.

Comment: what exactly isn't working? Retrieving the host name? What exactly fails? Is `HttpContext.Current` null? Or the request? or the URL? or...

Comment: I'm self-hosting Web API and HttpContext.Current is null.